# Python 3 Глобальные переменные

Tags: python

Всего доброго:) . Начал изучать питон, в шоке от того что тут нет модификаторов доступа(я с#'ист)

Есть такой код

```
a = 12
print(a)
def edit_a():
    a = 32
edit_a()
print(a)'
```

Вывод - '12' , '12'

Как на прямую изменить переменную `а`? Знаю, если это делать в классе то можно воспользоваться ссылкой на экземпляр self, но этот код находится вне класса

Comment: Не стоит внутри функции без очень веской причины менять переменные за её пределами. Лучше сделать, чтобы функция возвращала новое значение, а её вызов вместо edit_a() cделать a=edit_a()

Comment: Знаю,спасибо, просто мне был интересен механизм доступа к глобальным переменным вне класса. Однако, когда гуглил, попадались статьи, в которых было сказано, что для доступа к переменной вне метода, достаточно просто написать её имя

Comment: "для доступа к переменной вне метода, достаточно просто написать её имя" - видимо, имелся в виду доступ только для чтения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функции `edit_a` создаётся локальная переменная `a`, скрывающая глобальную. Чтобы этого избежать, надо использовать оператор [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global):

```
def edit_a():
    global a
    a = 32
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: @babyhn9 [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).